# Cloudways PHP FPM Settings — Semicolon?

Tags: php, wordpress, cloudways

Cloudways allows users to customize their PHP FPM settings. Silly question, I know, but if I want to change these items, where do I place the semicolon ";" ? They stated that by default they are inactive and suggest I remove the semicolons, at which point my site breaks. What should this code look like if I want to have a few items enabled and a few disabled? They are disabled by default (;php...), according to Cloudways.

```
;php_admin_flag[log_errors]=on
;php_admin_value[memory_limit]=128M
;php_admin_value[max_execution_time]=600
;php_admin_value[date.timezone]=America/New_York
;php_admin_value[max_input_time]=300
;php_admin_value[post_max_size]=48M
;php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize]=48M
;php_admin_value[max_input_vars]=3000
;php_admin_value[max_file_uploads]=20
;php_admin_value[display_errors]=off
```

Comment: If you want to enable a setting then you delete the semicolon from that line for only that item that you want to enable.  Then you can change the setting if needed `php_admin_value[display_errors]=on`

Comment: So for memory_limit:

    ;php_admin_flag[log_errors]=on
    php_admin_value[memory_limit]=128M
    ;php_admin_value[max_execution_time]=600
    ;php_admin_value[date.timezone]=America/New_York
    ;php_admin_value[max_input_time]=300
    ;php_admin_value[post_max_size]=48M
    ;php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize]=48M
    ;php_admin_value[max_input_vars]=3000
    ;php_admin_value[max_file_uploads]=20
    ;php_admin_value[display_errors]=off

? (sorry, bad formatting. I removed the second semicolon, they would be stacked as they were before)

Comment: @hgreenough Yes. Remove the `;` in the second line. A `;` in ini-files is equals to `#` or `//` in PHP, it's just a line that is commented out.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!